# Calculate with roots of unity

Tags: complex-analysis, cyclotomic-fields

I have extremly problems to calculate expressions with roots of unity.

How do I for example calculate something like this without the use of a calculator:

$$a=\frac{(e^{-i\frac{\pi}{4})^2}}{(e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}-e^{-i\frac{\pi}{4}})(e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}-e^{-3i\frac{\pi}{4}})(e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}-e^{3i\frac{\pi}{4}})}$$

$$b=(e^{-3i\frac{\pi}{4}}+e^{-i\frac{\pi}{4}})$$

Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: If $e^{i\pi/4}=a$


$$\dfrac{(a^{-1})^2}{(a-a^{-1})(a-a^{-3})(a-a^3)}=\dfrac{a\cdot a^3}{a^2(a^2-1)(a^4-1)a(1-a^2)}$$  See https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Exponent_Combination_Laws

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to work with kind of expressions is to see the geometry. First of all, I would locate the points in the circle. Then I would transform these points into coordinates. For example, if $a=e^{-i\frac{\pi}{4}}$ and $b=e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}$, then $$a=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i$$
and $$b=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i.$$
Finally I would use the vector nature of these numbers:
$$a^2=(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i)(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i)=-i$$ and 
$$a-b=(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i)-(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i)=-\sqrt{2}i.$$
I hope this helps you. I apologize for my english, it's not my native language.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your English is fine!